# Multiply a value by variable if it matches criteria, otherwise multiply by another variable

Tags: python, pandas

Hi why this kind of code dind't work? and how i can make it work with pandas?

I simply want to apply a different tax rate for a specifc product and another to all other products.

```
d = {'Product':['Banana','Orange','Grape'],
     'Value':[100,80,30]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

x = 0.25
y = 0.5

for value in df['Product']:
    if value=="Banana":
        df['Tax'] = df['Value'] * x
    else:
        df['Tax'] = df['Value'] * y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mask then apply it

```
mask = df['Product'].eq('Banana')
df.loc[mask, 'Tax'] = df['Value'] * x
df.loc[~mask, 'Tax'] = df['Value'] * y
```

or to save a few milliseconds, i think

```
df['Tax'] = df['Value'] * y
df.loc[df['Product'].eq('Banana'), 'Tax'] = df['Value'] * x
```